# Hiding 'aggregateRating' using CSS

Tags: css, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am working on a website for a client. They have marked up individual reviews that they display on their site with Microdata, but they have not included the corresponding `aggregateRating` property.

I have informed them that they need to include the `aggregateRating` propery in order to get Google to display stars in their organic listing. The client responded saying that this is okay, but I must hide any values associated with `aggregateRating` - (`ratingValue`, `ratingCount`) from the users who interact with their website.

I know that Google frowns upon this practice, but I want to know if anybody has had success hiding review Schema.org with CSS? By success I mean Google still displaying stars in organic listing.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to hide your schema using CSS. Not all schema data has to be shown on the web page. Consider JSON-LD schema, that's all in the `head` so none of those values are displayed.

HTML schema allows you to markup content that's not visible on the webpage.

[From Schema.org](https://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing):

> Sometimes, a web page has information that would be valuable to mark up, but the information can't be marked up because of the way it appears on the page […]
>
> […]
>
> ```
> <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
> ```

Full code snippet:

> ```
> <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
>   <span itemprop="name">Blend-O-Matic</span>
>   <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
>   <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope    itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
>     <img src="four-stars.jpg" />
>     <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
>     <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
>      Based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">25</span> user ratings
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```